# Memory-efficient data structure for matrix in PHP

Tags: php, performance, memory, matrix

I run out of memory, using a 80k x 20 matrix (array) of integer values in PHP. Is there a solution?

**Background**

I have a PHP application that collects data and stores it to a database. The data is collected in different domains (>20k). The number of variables varies throughout the domains (principally unlimited), so I have to store comma-separated lists in my MySQL database (before version 5). This performs quite well.

At some point of time, the user needs to download the data. The download feature must perform some normalization, therefore it needs the median (not average!) of each variable (actually the medians for a subset of the variables). Usually I can easily read the data from the database, explode() the comma-separated data and store the median-relevant data into an array[var][row]. Than i can sort() the arrays and I got the median.

However, there is one domain that does not have 100 or 1000 data records (rows), but 80K. Given 20 median-relevant variables, this is 1.6M integer values (with 32bit) or 51 MB raw integer data (probably twice as much, because I am working on a 64 bit Linux machine). So far, so good - but the array structure has some overhead, so it becomes much larger than 128 MB. This is the point where my PHP runs out of memory.

**What I do not want to do**

Of course, I could just increase the memory limit per PHP script. For various reasons, I would like to avoid this.

There also are algorithms that do not need to store n values to compute the median, but would be happy with n/2 (+x), but reducing the memory load to 50%+X may not be sufficient to solve the problem.

I also could calculate the medians variable per variable. But that would require me to load 80K rows of data from the database 20 times and to perform the explode() again, and again. This would dramatically increase the script run time.

[EDIT] The database is currently not normalized (using CSV data with each data row). This is intended and necessary for reasons of performance.  Therefore I do not like to normalize the database, as this would result in a table with 100M entries and a giant index.

**What I would like to do**

We're talking of no more then 51 MB of raw 32bit integer values. Is there any change to reduce the overhead to a few percent? Maybe even on a 64bit machine?

I know about the SPL extension that is available since PHP 5.0.0, but I did not yet find the solution how to save memory with this extension. Could anyone please give me a hint -- via SPL or using another solution (ideally available in PHP by default)?

**Sample Code**

```
private function retrieveReferences() {
    $query = $this->getResultsQuery(true);
    $times = array();
    $tp = -1; // Length of $times - 1
    while ($row = $query->fetchArray()) {
        $timeSrc = explode(',', $row['times']);

        // Store the times per page
        foreach ($timeSrc as $p=>$s) {
            // Should be faster than checking isset $times[$p] all the time
            while ($p > $tp) {
                $times[] = array();
                $tp = count($times) - 1;
            }
            $times[$p][] = (int)$s;
        }
    }
    // Compute median for each $times[$p]
    // <snip>
}
```

Comment: "The number of variables varies throughout the domains (principally unlimited), so I have to store comma-separated lists in my database." [No you do not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: or even http://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: I have read the whole story, but could you provide some code ? Maybe we could optimise it. Also if the DB is normalised you could do some calculations with mysql, but in this case it seems it is not. Without providing code, and you don't want to increase the memory limit: how would you expect us to help you ?

Comment: I believe this entire question is based on the fact you are not storing your data correctly and that once that is resolved this entire question is moot

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that I need to use MySQL < version 5. I don't think that there is an efficient way to store various-length data.

Comment: Wut? What various length data? You just told is they are `int`s. Just don't store data as serialized strings in a database. *Especially* if you need to query that data in whatever way.

Comment: I wanted to say: Records with a variable number of variables (10 in one domain, 1000 in another domain) - and as there are very many domains, I cannot create a single table for each one :(

Comment: you could just create a `domain_data` with a `domain_id` each time...

Comment: Please read the link about database normalization I linked before...

Comment: Hi! I had at least one course on database normalization during my studies ;) We're talking about 2 mio records in the database already - and growing. Each record has up to 2000 "variables" within the record. And there are many reading operations that need all variables within one record. Solving this with a normalized database would be very inefficient, therefore the comma-separated solution was chosen. Beyong the "median-relevant data" the data also includes strings, which makes normalization even more nasty. Sorry, I did not these details in my question.

Comment: A good relational database will be fine with 2M records, and if it is well indexed on good hardware, a figure many times that. Like PeeHaa, I am not yet convinced that CSV strings are an appropriate solution - they will be slow since you'll need to read them to process them, whereas holding records in the database will mean you can transfer processing to the database server.

Comment: Also, if you are worried about performance, can do you transfer any median-calculating to an offline process?

Comment: Yes, before de-normalizing also normalize. Try which variant really is faster. de-normalizing can have a benefit, but test that first. A testbed for this also allows you to run some different scripts to optimize things.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If de-nomrmalized, there would be about 200 mio. entries. Let alone the index of primary keys would like crush my database. But, worse, we'd need another value to identify the record. That alone makes nearly 200% disk overhead. And, again, there are many operations that read *all* data from one record and then write *all* data from the same record, again (every variable could change in the meantime). Actually, after having some experience with a 2M database table, I am really afraid from a 200M databse table :)

Comment: While reasoning about to CSV or not, I came across this page: http://we-love-php.blogspot.de/2012/06/php-memory-consumption-with-arrays.html - it shows a solution, I did not yet think about: Package the data into binary strings and store those in PHP (actually needs no more than 4 bytes per 32bit integer). Given that db normalization will not be my desired solution, I think I will give this a try...

Answer (score 1):

- An array consumes at least [104 bytes](https://gist.github.com/nikic/5015323), so the less arrays, the less memory usage.

  Switching to 1-dimentional arrays will save some amount of memory. Simply access the elements using an index computed like `$times[$item*$n_items + $sub_item]` instead of `$times[$item][$sub_item]`.
- Once you've done that, it's easy to switch to [`SplFixedArrays`](http://php.net/SplFixedArray), which will nearly eliminate the memory overhead of standard arrays (a standard arrays consumes up to [90 bytes](https://gist.github.com/nikic/5015323) per element).
- You could even eliminate the zval overhead by packing all the integers in a string

Comment: Seems you posted this answer while I posted my solution :) The overhead eliminated by the pack-as-string solution is enormous. Pointing out the arrray overhead and SplFixedArrays is generally a good advice, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution found on http://we-love-php.blogspot.de/2012/06/php-memory-consumption-with-arrays.html actually proved very helpful. I think it is worth, posting here:

> The most efficient kind of an array in PHP is a string.

Actually storing a large number of integer values within a string (4 bytes or characters for each integer) saves more than 80% (!) of memory. Of course there are lot of disadvantages: You need to encode/decode the integers, sorting requires custom functions, etc. Therefore, this solution is only sensible when memory really matters.

In my case, 16-bit integers were sufficient, so I could encode each integer with 2 characters. Here is the sample code I employed:

```
private function retrieveReferences() {
    $query = $this->getResultsQuery(true);
    $timesSE = array();
    $tp = -1; // Length of $times - 1
    while ($row = $query->fetchArray()) {
        $timeSrc = explode(',', $row['times']);

        // Store the times per page
        foreach ($timeSrc as $p=>$s) {
            // Should be faster than checking isset $times[$p] all the time
            while ($p > $tp) {
                $timesSE[] = '';
                $tp = count($timesSE) - 1;
            }
            // Save to limit to 16bit (in this specific case)
            $i = (int)$s;
            if ($i > 0xFFFF) {
                $i = 0xFFFF;
            }
            $timesSE[$p].= chr(($i & 0xFF00) >> 8).chr($i & 0x00FF);
        }
    }
    // Compute median for each $times[$p]
    // <snip>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be hitting a memory limit as the data will be at a minimum of 6.5M

Need to look at you php.ini file. Was original defaulted to 8M

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: Thanks. But ... The limit actually is 128M. In my opinion, no PHP script _should_ exceed that limit ;)